# Why does `df.astype('int')` change the value of the number?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was testing some code and found out about this quirk of pandas:
Let's say you have a float number in your df, for example `57.99999999999999` but you need that number as an int, so you do `df.astype('int')`. The number you get is `57` (instead of `58`).
Does anyone know why that happens?

Here's some code to prove my point:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [57.99999999999999]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [57.999999999999997]})
print(df.astype('int'))
print(df2.astype('int'))
```

I've noticed that while `57.99999999999999` and `57.999999999999996` get both converted to 57, `57.999999999999997` gets converted to `58`.

Comment: This isn't really Pandas-related: in plain Python, `int(57.99999999999999)` gives 57 and `int(57.999999999999997)` gives 58.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's `float` inaccuracies, nothing specific to `pandas` or even `python`. `float` cannot save floating point numbers with arbitrary precision, see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) As a quick test without pandas, see this output from an interactive python session

```
>>>l=57.999999999999997
>>> l
58.0
>>>
```

Comment: Yeah, but without the last 7 it also is 58 (it took me like 1h to figure out that the value 58 in the debugger was not 58 but 57.999999999)

Comment: I don't know what you mean, in your own question, you wrote that `57.999999999` gets (correctly) converted to 57 when converted to int. Conversion to int is always rounding down

Comment: OK, I retested that outside the program and seems to work right. It's a problem with floating point numbers. Seems more a problem with the VScode representation than with python...